# How to split a large .tar.gz on a Windows machine to upload on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, upload, tar, gzip

I downloaded a rather large (6GB) backup file from a cloud Linux server about a week ago before it went down to my Windows laptop. We just got ourselves a new cloud server just now and the decision has been made to redeploy the site on said server.

Now, we're a small company using a high-end, but ultimately consumer-grade, internet connection and while the download speed is fairly decent, upload is lacking.

I plan on uploading the file over the course of a week or two and I'm wondering if there's a tool out there that can split this file into multiple segments so I can upload them (using FTP) in relatively bite-sized pieces. A search on Google and on this site failed me and mostly point to instructions on splitting it on a Linux server. While it's all well and good, we don't have an on-premise Linux server. Bonus points for a link on how to rejoin them after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a client that can resume such as WinSCP.

Or BitTorrent on a private tracker. Bonus: built in verification of all the chunks.

If you still would like multi part archives, there are multiple tools capable of doing that such as 7zip. Multi part archives generally require an archive program at at both ends that can handle the format. I'm sure there are ways to do the equivalent of GNU coreutils `split` on Windows, I don't have the PowerShell handy of how to do it.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but I'll give it a shot. Thanks for trying. I'm still open to other answers though. I do happen to have WinSCP at home.

Comment: You can find split and concatenate examples for your favorite scripting langugae. Here's one PowerShell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533570/in-powershell-how-do-i-split-a-large-binary-file    Python or Perl implementations can also be found.  Or you can use a coreutils split on  Cygwin or Windows Subsystem for Linux. Lots of choices.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [gsplit3](http://www.gdgsoft.com/download/gsplit.aspx) utility.

Answer (score 0):

google tells me [hjsplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/) or [gsplit](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/) might do the trick for you.